# Detectability of a particular system implies detectability of a subsystem. (Eigenvalue problem)

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

I am looking at the system
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{pmatrix} \dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2 \end{pmatrix} &=& 
\begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} + 
\begin{pmatrix} B_1 \\ B_2 \end{pmatrix} u,\\
y &=& \begin{pmatrix} I_{p} & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}
which is assumed to be detectable. That is, there exists a matrix $\tilde{G}$ such that
    \begin{equation}
        \sigma \left( 
            \begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{pmatrix} 
            - 
            \tilde{G} 
            \begin{pmatrix} I_{p} & 0 \end{pmatrix}
        \right)
        \subset \mathbb C^{-}.\quad (*)
    \end{equation}
I want to show that this implies that the pair $(A_{12},A_{22})$ is also detectable, that is, to show that there exists a matrix $G$ such that
    \begin{equation}
        \sigma(A_{22} - GA_{12}) \subset \mathbb C^{-}\quad (**)
    \end{equation}
is also satisfied.

My working so far is as follows:

We know that $\tilde{G} \in \mathbb R^{n \times p }$ can be written as $\tilde{G} = \begin{pmatrix} G_1^T & G_2^T\end{pmatrix}^T$ so that the previous equation becomes
    \begin{equation}
        \sigma 
        \begin{pmatrix} A_{11} - G_1& A_{12} \\ A_{21} -G_2 & A_{22} \end{pmatrix} 
        \subset \mathbb C^{-}.
    \end{equation}
I am unsure how to continue after this. I am think I am probably on the right track though. I want to deduce something about the eigenvalues in $(**)$ using the information of the eigenvalues in $(*)$.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalent definition of detectability is the following:

Let $A,C$ matrices with dimensions $n\times n$ and  $p\times n$ respectively.  $(C,A)$ is detectable if $rank\left[\matrix{C\\A-\lambda \mathbb{I}}\right]=n$ for all $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}^+$.

From the detectability assumption we have that
$$rank\left[\matrix{\mathbb{I}_p & 0\\A_{11}-\lambda \mathbb{I}_p & A_{12}\\ A_{21} & A_{22}-\lambda\mathbb{I}_{n-p}}\right]=n\:,\qquad \forall \lambda\in \mathbb{C}^+$$
In the above matrix the first $p$ columns are linearly independent from the rest $n-p$ columns. Thus, in order the matrix to have full column rank $n$ the following must hold
$$rank\left[\matrix{ 0\\ A_{12}\\  A_{22}-\lambda\mathbb{I}_{n-p}}\right]=n-p\:,\qquad \forall \lambda\in \mathbb{C}^+$$
or equivalently
$$rank\left[\matrix{ A_{12}\\  A_{22}-\lambda\mathbb{I}_{n-p}}\right]=n-p\:,\qquad \forall \lambda\in \mathbb{C}^+$$
The last condition means that $(A_{12},A_{22})$ is detectable.

Comment: ah thats a nice clear approach. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Slugger You are welcome!